# youtube api v3 next page token not returned for a search

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of video ids for a youtube channel that does not have an associated playlist. It contains 134 videos, hence I am trying to use next page token as explained in related posts on this forum, however, in my search results i do not get a next page token. The python code for this is as below.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import json

DEVELOPER_KEY = "myserverkey set in google console"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

#search_response = youtube.search().list(part="id",type="video",fields="items/id", order ="viewCount", maxResults= 50).execute()
search_response = youtube.search().list(
    channelId="UCgxzjK6GuOHVKR_08TT4hJQ",
    part="id",
    type="video",
    fields="items/id",
    order ="viewCount",
    maxResults=50
).execute()

videos = []
ytnextpagetoken = search_response.get("nextPageToken")

for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    videos.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

print(len(videos))
print(ytnextpagetoken)
```

Basically, I want to iterate over the values of the next page token and get a list, then once I have those, I can filter out the videos that I want too see and embed them on my page.

Please can you tell me what I am doing incorrectly.

I also tried channel.list but that does not return a playlist.

Regards,
Arjun